# I cant deserialize from xml

Tags: c#, serialization

I have problem with deserialize from XML.

My code to deserialize is:

```
public void wczytaj()
    {
        StringReader reader = new StringReader("sklep.txt");
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Sklep));
        Sklep sklep = (Sklep) serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        reader.Close();
    }
```

Main part of Sklep class

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("Sklep")]
public class Sklep : IKlient, IProdukt, IRachunek, IWKlient, IWProdukt, IWRachunek
{
    public List<Klient> listKlienci = new List<Klient>();
    public List<Produkt> listProdukty = new List<Produkt>();
    public ObservableCollection<Rachunek> ocRachunki = new ObservableCollection<Rachunek>();
```

When i compile that program, i have "An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Xml.dll"

Additional information: Dokument XML zawiera błąd (1, 1).

XML Document has error (1,1)

What i have to do with that? I want to deserialize this class.

XML file:

http://pastebin.com/VVNgSZpM <-- Sorry i forgotten

Comment: You'll need to post the XML to get a good answer.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with XML.  Are you sure your reader opens the file correctly?  Can you validate and as a test read reader into a string, and validate that you get the same XML in there?

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
StringReader reader = new StringReader("sklep.txt");
```

is reading the literal string "sklep.txt" and and the next lines are trying to parse that as XML (which it isn't). Maybe:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("sklep.txt");
```

or:

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(path);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add the matching Attributes to your Propertys:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("Sklep")]
public class Sklep : IKlient, IProdukt, IRachunek, IWKlient, IWProdukt, IWRachunek
{
    [XmlArray,XmlArrayItem]
    public List<Klient> listKlienci = new List<Klient>();
    [XmlArray,XmlArrayItem]
    public List<Produkt> listProdukty = new List<Produkt>();
    [XmlArray,XmlArrayItem]
    public ObservableCollection<Rachunek> ocRachunki
```

Additional Explanation:

```
[XmlRoot]
public class Sklep
{
    [XmlArray, XmlArrayItem]
    public List<Klient> listKlienci = new List<Klient>();
}
[XmlType]
public class Klienci
{
    [XmlElement]
    public string Imie;
}
```

Your XmlTypes or Roots must contain a parameterless constructor and every Xml-Attribute-Field must be public.

Comment: Are your Klient(and Product....) Propertys also Properly Tagged with [XmlElement]?